# My OTP Working well in firebase using android in debug apk but not working in release

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

its saying project is not correctly authentication invalid code verification use the correct Sha and Package.means i have put everything correct in firebase for debug apk but its  not working for relase apk, i have to use another sha for relase???

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps:
 1. Login to Google publish console(playstore) and select the published app.
 2. Goto Release management and select app signing.
 3. From app signing certificate copy the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

Use this SHA in firebase.